# Converting an Excel Formula into SQL Report Builder Expression

Tags: sql, reporting-services, excel-formula, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

I have been given an excel formula and I need it to work in SSRS Report Builder 3.0 as an expression, This is the original Excel formula:

**IF(A01>12,ROUND(A01/24,0),1)**

Instead of cell A01 the value field in SSRS is called **[diff]**

Essentially its an expression to round a number of hours into number of days but the hours aren't inputted in 24's.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=IIF(Fields!diff.Value>12,ROUND(Fields!diff.Value/24.0),1)
```

Let me know if this helps.